# Has China censored news that's critical of Israel?

Tags: china, israel

The Chinese regime censoring news critical of China is nothing new. Is there any example of China censoring news critical of Israel? [Mondoweiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondoweiss) is a progressive American outlet known for being impartial with Israel. I'm asking because [according to Mondoweiss](https://hachyderm.io/@mondoweiss@mastodon.social/109779375028519340) they had their TikTok channel banned. They've also been vocal on Chinese-Israel deals, like this article from 2015,

- [Israel’s new Asian allies](https://mondoweiss.net/2015/02/israels-asian-allies/)

Which published this,

> Ties between Israel and China are deepening rapidly too. Beijing has become Israel’s third largest trading partner, while Israel is China’s second biggest supplier of military technology after Russia. Last month the two signed a three-year cooperation plan, with China keen to exploit – in addition to Israel’s military hardware – its innovations on solar energy, irrigation and desalination.

Comment: Why should they? Israel is an allie of USA not China.

Comment: @convert That doesn't preclude them from taking action to get on their good side.

Comment: -1 mondoweiss is not impartial to Israel, it is decidedly anti-Israel and anti-zionist. It has also been called an antisemitic hate site for it's use of antisemitic imagery.

Comment: *Mondoweiss* is not "known for being impartial with Israel." As you note, the blog is has an explicit progressive leaning, and does not seek impartiality but rather morality. As such, it is known for (on the better side) explicitly opposing Israeli atrocities against Palestinians, criticizing the Israel-US alliance, and criticizing imperialist and racist strains in Israeli politics, and (on the worse side) publishing cartoons equating Israel with Nazi Germany, supporting Hezbollah, complaining about "the presence of Jews in the power structure" impeding better policy toward Israel, etc.

Comment: I will not presume to say which of those stands is more dominant or more important in its commentary, but neither represents impartiality.

Comment: That said, it is not incorrect to say that the Chinese government and social media companies have occasionally cracked down on things that could be viewed as antithetical to the Israeli government. For instance, discussion of the al-Aqsa Mosque was prohibited om the Chinese app HelloTalk for a while. It is important to view this in context, however: the Chinese government has a strong bias toward *stability*. They like to censor things related to protests in general, for fear that people in China could get the wrong (right?) ideas.

Comment: @Obie2.0 By trends in US media, all those things would be considered to be "impartial" on Israel.  Those things, and more, have been said by sitting members of US Congress.

Comment: @Ertai87 - If you think *politicians* are *impartial*, perhaps you are on the wrong website. Politicians are people whose careers depend on the very opposite of impartiality.

Comment: My point is that the examples cited are mainstream examples of things said about Israel in arenas in which impartiality is expected, and those people are not censured; therefore those things are, by definition, stances of impartiality.

Comment: That is not correct. Most fundamentally, impartiality is not expected in any political arena save the judiciary. No one expects the Democratic members of Congress to describe the Republicans' policy as if they were the Associated Press or vice versa. It's also mistaken to believe that any statement on Israel in the US Congress is not subject to censure: Republicans and some Democrats invariably criticize the statements of other Democrats on Israel, and those Democrats criticize them right back. There have even been some formal votes of censure.

Comment: It is also incorrect to equate impartiality with how much criticism someone receives in domestic politics, rather than what it actually is—about taking sides (impartiality is not the same as morality, either!) "Death to the dirty Communists" wasn't a particularly criticized political position during most of McCarthyism, but to call it an impartial evaluation of the Soviet Union would be severely stretching things.

Comment: @Obie2.0 your argument is unconvincing. You've created a dichotomy that doesn't exist. You can be impartial and still call out things that others are likely to view as immoral. As a specific point, I'm sure Israel would agree more than 5 million died in the Holocaust which was a genocide that included socialists, Jews, and other ethnic and political minorities. That's not partial because it's reporting on something with a moral dynamic, no one would call it that. Likewise, saying Palestinians should be against Zionism, or that Jews should be against Nazism doesn't sound to me to be partial.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - There is no dichotomy: some things can be impartial and moral at the same time, for instance. You're just using the word "impartial" to mean "objective" and "moral" at the same time, neither of which its common meaning. As illustrated in your comment: the first description of the Holocaust is objectively correct and impartial—though your framing of it, such as substantially low-balling the numbers, is questionable. The latter two statements—people *should* be against this thing—are not impartial, and cannot be objective (as statements of opinion), but they are moral.

Comment: Although I again question your kind of odd framing of the statements —is it fine for Palestinians to be in favor of Nazism or Jews to be in favor of Zionism?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142476/discussion-between-evan-carroll-and-obie-2-0).

Comment: Could it be that China censors religious extremism, and that platform said something like protecting Al Aqsa by force etc.?

Comment: It's obviously different from an American prospective and also from a Soviet perspective. We clearly agree with the use of force to achieve moral ends. I'd go so far as to say, it must also be true in China's case too. However, feel free to challenge that notion. =)

Comment: China's regime of censorship is pervasive and I have little doubt that at some point in time it has censored something that happened to include statements critical of Israel. The harder question is whether that was why particular things were censored, or if instead the censorship was primarily for some other reason peculiar to China. For example, the PRC tends to be uncomfortable discussing religion generally and discussions of Israel frequently involve discussions of religion as well. Likewise China might be uncomfortable with discussions of violent insurgencies that its people could imitate.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might depend on the time. There is a time back in the 90s when Israel helped China developed its military technology. I think upto that point China would not show any news pieces critical of Israel. Coincidentally, that is the same time when a flood of books praising the Jewish people's book-loving and tiger parenting (There are talks in China about how Jews put honey on books and let babies lick them to get them "hook on book-reading", and how Jewish people have massive bookshelves in their homes, and how Jews basically do tiger parenting before China make it a thing). And they also have lots of books telling Chinese that Jews have superb business skills and money-making mindsets that allow them to make money in anywhere--and how to think and be like them so the Chinese can make money anywhere too.

And after Israel cave to US pressure and stopped giving China tech, the kind of praising stopped.